# Comparison operator not working in if statement PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

This below is printing `hello` even though the statement is `false`

```
$Originating_country_region = $country_region[$i]['region'];      // value of var is AM after assigning
$order_shipping_country_region = $country_region[$i]['region'];   // value of var is EU after assigning

if(isset($Originating_country_region) == "EU" && isset($order_shipping_country_region) == "EU")
{
 echo "Hello";
}
```

Comment: use `$Originating_country_region == "EU"` directly

Comment: @Anant than how can i compare?

Comment: @ChetanAmeta i cant compare directly as it will give undefined error when value will be empty because its in a loop

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan  please mark and up-vote the answer. you can up-vote other if they are useful too.

Comment: why people are not marking answer even they got solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing the return value of isset, and not the contents of the variables directly. Try:

```
if((isset($Originating_country_region) && $Originating_country_region) == "EU") && (isset($order_shipping_country_region) && $order_shipping_country_region == "EU"))
```

This checks that the codes are first of all set, and then checks their values.

It's a useful trick to learn :-)

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan Cool! Can you accept the answer then? Either mine or Anant's, since we both gave the same answer :-)